# Print ">" on every line

Tags: php

How would I do to print a ">" before every line?

```
if ($quoteid) {
echo ' 
> '.$quote['message'].' 
'; 
}
```

Currently It Looks like this:

```
> I would move Heaven and Hell and anything in between to get to you. 
You wouldn't be safe anywhere if I was mad at you.
And that's not bull; that's truth. I've went up against people.
You could pull a gun on me and if I'm mad at you I'm coming forward.
You'd have to shoot me to stop me and if you don't kill me... you're stupid cause the next time you see me I will kill you.
```

I want it to look like this:

```
> I would move Heaven and Hell and anything in between to get to you. 
> You wouldn't be safe anywhere if I was mad at you.
> And that's not bull; that's truth. I've went up against people.
> You could pull a gun on me and if I'm mad at you I'm coming forward.
> You'd have to shoot me to stop me and if you don't kill me... you're stupid cause the next time you see me I will kill you.
```

Comment: Replace the newline character with a newline then '> '.  Not sure of the specifics in PHP though. Hope that helps..

Answer (score 10):

```
if ($quoteid) {
    // Replace new line with new line + "> "
    echo '>' . str_replace("\n", "\n> ", $quote['message']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($quoteid) { 
   echo ' > '.str_replace("\n","\n > ",$quote['message'])';  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use str_getcsv or explode to get the lines of your textblock and then print every line (like you already do).

Answer (score 0):

try with  [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$bodytag = str_replace("\n", ">", $quote['message']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"), "\n> ", $quote['message']);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this sinp

```
if ($quoteid) {
    echo str_replace("\n", "\n> ", $quote['message']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '&gt;'.substr("\n", "\n&gt;", $quote['message']);
```